# KUKA Youbot navigation simulation

Tags: ros, navigation, simulation, kuka, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, 
I want to apply navigation with a Youbot in simulation. I used the simulator provided by ROS and I launch it with the following command: 
*roslaunch youbot_gazebo_robot youbot.launch*

But when I try to move the robot after doing the following indications to bring up the navigation stack: http://wiki.ros.org/youbot_navigation , the robot doesn't move. I have some errors with the hokuyo_node.

I found that the youbot_oodl package provided here: https://github.com/youbot/youbot-ros-pkg/tree/master/youbot_drivers/youbot_oodl is not functional (the OODL include files are missing).

If someone can help me, I will be grateful,

lfr

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234600/kuka-youbot-navigation-simulation/) by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2016-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A collaborator and I had gotten that working a few months ago, but not using the official `youbot_navigation` that you mentioned. Instead, take a look at this: https://github.com/pschillinger/youbot_integration it might help (You can safely ignore the "behavior" stuff; it's specific to our project.)

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-05-20**:
Thank you, I'll try that

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-05-20**:
I used  the launch inside the youbot_navigation package but I have a problem. When I try to move the robot, the arm moves instead of the base. But the problem doesn't come from your package (the same problem appears with my own nodes).

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-05-20**:
It's okay, I found my mistake. I used base_link intead of odom as fixed frame. It works correctly now. Thanks again.

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-05-23**:
Sorry, I have another problem, I cannot see obstacles in the costmap and I don't know why. Can you help me ?

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-05-23**:
I'm pretty sure we have not configured the costmaps fully. Take a look at https://github.com/fetchrobotics/fetch_ros/tree/indigo-devel/fetch_navigation and https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/indigo/turtlebot_navigation for examples of how to configure them.

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-05-23**:
Thanks, I found where is the error: I replaced the map_type value which was voxel to costmap and it works.
Thank you again.

**Comment by [Aff](https://answers.ros.org/users/39938/aff/) on 2019-02-09**:
i can't compile the packages because of an error :invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘steered_wheel_base_controller::SteeredWheelBaseController’
return new C;
have you some tips?

**Comment by [Aff](https://answers.ros.org/users/39938/aff/) on 2019-02-10**:
i solved that prblem, but now i'm stucked on this:
Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to odom to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame odom does not exist.. canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1.

it's my first simulation